# Which one is better approach for initialize flutter widget properties?

Tags: flutter, dart

Which one is better approach for initialize flutter widget properties?

can someone explain which approach is better and why.

#### First one

having `const constructor` and initialize properties in `build` method.

```dart
class CustomStatusBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomStatusBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.report,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Report report;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int open = report.open;
    final int finished = report.finished;
    final int terminated = report.terminated;
    final int total = open + finished + terminated;

    return MyWidget();
  }
}
```

#### Second one

having `Non-cost constructor` and initialize properties in `constructor`.

```dart
class CustomStatusBar extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomStatusBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.report,
  }) :
  open = report.open,
  finished = report.finished,
  terminated = report.terminated,
  total = report.open + report.finished + report.terminated,
  super(key: key);

  final Report report;
  final int open;
  final int finished;
  final int terminated;
  final int total;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyWidget();
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no point in declaring ``open``, ``finished``, ``terminated`` in the first place when you already have the ``report`` and you can access using the three values via it.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor is a special function of the class that is responsible for **initializing the variables of the class.**

As per your example you are trying to initialise final variable of the class which you need to initialise when class is created. (**variables with final keyword can't be reassigned and modified**)

Also when you initialise variable in constructor it will be assigned once. But if you define it in build method it will assign each time when the widget rebuild. (Not in case of variables with final keyword)

**So second approach is the best way to define a widget.**

Answer (score 0):

Second 100%, do not declare nothing in build method. The reason is that build method can be called multiple times during build of widget